# Convert csv into Json using python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have an csv file of having data I want to convert into json format but I get issue about the formation.

Data input in csv file:

[image]

Data shown in Dataframe:
[image]

The data format I want in json:

```
[restaurant name: 
  Address:
  Sate:
  Logo:
  Review:
    menu: {
    food name
    food price
    
    },
    {
    food name
    food price
    
    },
]
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't get the desired result.

Here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'.\test.csv')
print(df)

df.to_json(r'.\test.json', orient='values')
```

Is there anyway to get the results of that format?

EDIT: a minimal dataset to illustrate

```
Restaurant_Name,Address,State,Logo,Review,Menu,Price
"Taiwan bubble tea","Taipei,Taiwan","bestille","http://url",6,"Classic milk tea","47kr"
"Taiwan bubble tea","Taipei,Taiwan","bestille","http://url",6,"Matcha Mlik tea","47kr"
"Taiwan bubble tea","Taipei,Taiwan","bestille","http://url",6,"Melon Milk tea","47kr"
"Taiwan bubble tea","Taipei,Taiwan","bestille","http://url",6,"Mango tea","47kr"
```

Comment: provide the dataframe as code not a picture

Comment: A csv file is a **TEXT** file. When you print the way it is shown in a spreasheet editor like Excel, you do not show the separators, nor the possible quotation marks, and numbers or date can be re-interpreted. Please show as text. You can use the `cat` command on Unix-like systems, or `type` on Windows or open it in a text editor like notepad, notepad++, vi, ...

Comment: @gold_cy, I have update the question hope you are understand what i am trying to say

Comment: @SergeBallesta Can you give an proper guideline to done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with

```
(df
    .rename(columns={"Menu":"food_name"}) # change column name to have "food_name" instead of "Menu" in the resulting nested JSON
    .groupby(["Restaurant_Name", "Address", "State", "Logo", "Review"])
    .apply(lambda x: x[["food_name", "Price"]].to_dict('records'))
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0:"Menu"})
    .to_json(r"yourJSONfile.json", orient="records", indent=4))
```

1. First the data is `groupby`ed the characteristic of the restaurant (Name, address, state, logo, and review), and for each restaurant we transform all the rows into an array of dicts containing info about the food
2. After resetting the index, you obtain a dataframe with one row per restaurant, with the last column named 0, and containing the array of menu items with their price.
3. Because it's prettier and it makes sense, we rename the column 0 to "Menu"
4. the function to_json with the orient='records' then can write the dataframe as a JSON file, as an array with one entry per restaurant (= 1 row of the dataframe), each key being one column name. In particular, the "Menu" key will have the array of food items.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: But where the file has been created?

Comment: Just edited the answer so that your data is exported to the "yourJSONfile.json" file

Comment: Without the "r'yourJSONfile.json'" argument in the to_json function, pandas just returns the string representation of your JSON data without saving it to a file

Comment: Thank you for this but it doesn't give the desire output

Comment: Edited the answer to fit your needs and provide a bit more explanation. Sorry if it's not clear (3am where I am). Let me know if you're happy with the result, or if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much I am getting the result I want. Thank you so much for your help